# SUM timestamp with the most recent date field

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

I want to sum a timestampdiff with of most recent date field, so what I did:

```
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MAX(date), MAX(date_last_up))) as diff
```

Turns out this triggers an error in MySql (Invalid use of group function) and I had to remove the `MAX()` function to get it to work:

```
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date, date_last_up)) as diff
```

Someone knows how to do that with the MAX() function ?

Comment: Not to sure, but try something like `SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, SELECT MAX(date) FROM tbl LIMIT 1, MAX(date_last_up))) AS boobs`

Comment: Are the fields grouped by anything? Ie, are you looking for the total of all the differences in those timestamps (in which case you probably want a subselect with a different group by clause)?

Comment: You can't using one grouping function (MAX) inside another (SUM). What are you trying to accomplish? Can you post some sample data and the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it something like that

```
   select yourcolumn , SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, max_date, date_last_up)) 
  from (
         select yourcolumn , MAX(date) as max_date , MAX(date_last_up) as date_last_up
         WHERE ....
      )as t
   GROUP by yourcolumn
```